# Why are transaction times not included in MySQL slow query log lock times

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking

### The Problem

In the MySQL slow query log I am seeing queries that are taking a large amount of time and this is because multiple concurrent transactions are updating the same row:

```
# Time: 130322 17:42:07
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 48.500955  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
use test;
SET timestamp=1363974127;
UPDATE test SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

Why are waiting on transactions not counted in the Lock_time and so what is counted?

### To Reproduce

Here's how you can reproduce the slow query entry. Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   count INT NOT NULL
);
```

and then insert a row:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1);
```

If I then start up 2 connections to the database with autocommit turned off and in the first one run:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE test SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 1;
```

and then use the second connection to run:

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE test SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

then wait a short amount of time to make this a slow query and then return to the first connection and do the commit:

```
COMMIT;
```

I get the slow query entry from the start of the question.

Comment: Are you really interested in the *why*? Or are you interested in a way to get them included?

Comment: Slow queries log will give you logs at query level, not at the transaction level. Transaction level slow query log hasnt made any sense to me as it might wait for resource for which you cant do much about

Comment: To me waiting on a transaction is a lock and I would have expected it to be included in the lock time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in MySQL which was not reporting the full lock time under InnoDB and is fixed in MySQL 5.5.6:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53496